# Find values that are start of SearchString

Tags: mysql, sql

For a given search string **s**, I want to find values from an indexed varchar(255) field (~1m rows), so that s.startsWith(value) == true.

Example: 
**s** = "hello world"

matches: "h", "hello", "hello world"

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) with opposite arguments than one would do in most cases:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  INSTR('hello world', mycol) = 1
```

This will return records where *mycol* has a substring of "hello world" starting at position 1. So any of the following will match:

> h
>   he
>   hel
>   hell
>   hello
>   hello (with trailing space)
>   hello w
>   hello wo
>   hello wor
>   hello worl
>   hello world

You could maybe get better performance with the addition of the following redundant condition, which could hint the SQL engine to choose an index on mycol:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  INSTR('hello world', mycol) = 1
AND    mycol like 'h%'
```

Just be aware that even with use of an index this does not guarantee a faster output. Imagine a table with values:

> hel
>   helaaaaaaa
>   helaaaaaab
>   helaaaaaac
>   ...(1000 more records like that, and finally:)
>   hello world

... then the engine would still scan all records, and only get the first and the last.

If you have an application executing this query, you could let it build the SQL dynamically, so that it looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  mycol IN ('h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell', 'hello', 'hello ', 'hello w', 
                 'hello wo', 'hello wor', 'hello worl', 'hello world')
```

This would have potentially the best performance. If that doesn't do it, then certainly this elaborate SQL will do it:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'h'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'he'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hel'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hell'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hello'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hello '
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hello w'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hello wo'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hello wor'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hello worl'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol = 'hello world'
```

Comment: Will an index will be used here, if used with ` = 1`?

Comment: You can check with `EXPLAIN PLAN` on your instance. If not, you could add `AND mycol like 'h%'`, which is redundant but could help the engine to detect the benefit of using an index.

Comment: Good idea, I think of a min length anyway, so I could use an additional 'hel%'

Comment: I'd like to give another +1 for the IN solution:) I will try this later, and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `like` for this:

```
where col like 'hello%' -- or whatever
```

or

```
where col like concat(@s, '%')
```

The reason for using `like` is that it can make use of an index, because the pattern does not start with wildcard characters.

EDIT:

I might have the logic backwards.  If so, you can still use like:

```
where @s like concat(col, '%')
```

In this case, though, an index cannot be used, because the column is an argument to a function.

Comment: I will give it a try, but I fear it's too slow if index cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "like" in sql.

> select * from tableName 
>   where columnName like 'h%'